# Oracle equivalent of PostgreSQL Hstore

Tags: oracle

Hstore is a schema less key value store inside of PostgreSQL that allows us to store data like hashes directly inside of a column

More infor here
http://schneems.com/post/19298469372/you-got-nosql-in-my-postgres-using-hstore-in-rails

What is the equivalent of this in Oacle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle offer a "Big Data" NoSQL system, but not as part of the relational DBMS

http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/nosql/overview/index.html